# transparent JButton when clicked using SystemLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, look-and-feel

I've prepared transparent Button class:

```
public MyButton() {

        super("button");
        setOpaque(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorder(null);
        setBorderPainted(false);
    }
```

But button is not fully transparent. When it is clicked it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this annoying rectangle? 
There is no such problem in default L&F but I'd like to use SystemLookAndFeel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
setFocusPainted(false);
```

Note: All the above functionality can be achieved by just creating an instance of `JButton` and using rather than sub-classing the component

Comment: Background of button will be changed when there is mouse over it or button is clicked. 
Thank you :)